# Modifying the operating frequency (for 802.11ac) on ns-3

Tags: wifi, ns-3

I am attempting to change the operating frequency to 300MHz (to simulate the working of 802.11af) but retain the overall PHY layer configuration of 802.11ac.

I have gone through earlier posts and realized that the SetFrequency() function (in the class YansWifiPhy) can be employed. However, when I implement the following statement ('wifi' is an object of the class WifiHelper)-

NetDeviceContainer staDevices = wifi.Install (phy, mac, wifiStaNodes);

I get an error since the object 'phy' is required to be of YansWifiPhyHelper datatype, not YansWifiPhy. However, I can't seem to change the frequency using the YansWifiPhyHelper class. How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see *YansWifiPhy* is a child class of *WifiPhy*. The *typeId* of *WifiPhy* has **Frequency** as an attribute. You can set this attribute using any to of the following way:

1. You can change the default value of **ns3::WifiPhy::Frequency** using the **Config::SetDefault** function. The documentation for the same can be found [here](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/manual/html/attributes.html#config-setdefault-and-commandline).
2. Secondly you can use the **Set** function of *YansWifiPhyHelper* to set any attribute of *YansWifiPhy (WifiPhy)*. You can find an example of this  [here](http://code.nsnam.org/ns-3-dev/file/069e6f209960/examples/wireless/wifi-tcp.cc#l97). The only difference from the link will be that you need to change the attribute name to **Frequency** and change the value accordingly.

Please, let me know in case of any doubts or any of these don't work for you.